# Functions and condition statements

Tags: python

I wanted to know if it is possible to put condition statements inside a function, where depending on which condition is executed, it'll move onto another function.

For example:

```
def main():
    animal = input("Enter an animal name: ")
    if animal == cow:
        cow()
    else:
        other()

def cow():
    print("You entered cow")

def other():
    print("You didn't enter cow")

main()
```

Comment: you need quotes around the string: `if animal == 'cow':`

Comment: Yes, it's possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. And your example is almost exactly how you would do it. However, you have one issue in your code, and that is your `if` condition. You need to check if the value returned by `animal` is a string, not a function or variable as it is currently doing.

you would do this by changing it to:

`if animal == "cow":`

Comment: @AGNGazer: No it wouldn't. But it would be nice.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can implement a control structure inside of a function which can determine which function to use. I would change your code to be:

```
def main():
    animal = input("Enter an animal name: ")
    if (animal == 'cow'):
        cow()
    else:
        other()

def cow():
    print("You entered cow")

def other():
    print("You didn't enter cow")

main()
```

This would allow the input to be properly compared with cow (string to string comparison).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the code you have is almost perfect. The only issue is that when you do the comparison, you need to put quotes around cow so that python knows you are trying to compare to the string "cow" and not some undefined variable cow. Also, you can use the .lower() method on the animal variable if you want to make it case insensitive. The following code works properly:

```
def main():
    animal = input("Enter an animal name: ")
    if animal.lower() == "cow":
        cow()
    else:
        other()

def cow():
    print("You entered cow")

def other():
    print("You didn't enter cow")

main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this it's much shorter:

```
def main():
    animal = input("Enter an animal name: ")
    cow() if animal == 'cow' else other()

def cow():
    print("You entered cow")

def other():
    print("You didn't enter cow")

main()
```

Outputs:

```
Enter an animal name: cow
You entered cow

Enter an animal name: snake
You didn't enter cow
```